# django when edit the data from data base

Tags: django

i am tryong to edit the data from database i am getting error at **update_user_id** for more info please look at this link then u will understood please

**http://www.pastie.org/1301839**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't set the `update_user_id` key in your session. You can work around this problem using exceptions:

```
try:
    update_user_id = request.session["update_user_id"]
except KeyError:
    update_user_id = SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE
```

Or (even better) by using `request.session.get`:

```
update_user_id = request.session.get("update_user_id", SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE)
```

The two snippets are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

From your traceback:

```
Exception Type: KeyError at /institutes_admin/
Exception Value: 'update_user_id'
```

A KeyError means that you tried to get something from a dictionary using a dictionary key that didn't exist. This looks like the problem (from further up the traceback):

```
File "/home/karthik/Desktop/EPW_LOCAL/mysite/../mysite/epw/admin_views.py" in institutional_ip_admin
  604.   update_user_id = request.session['update_user_id']
```

A solution would be to provide a default value.